# reduce HTTPS waiting time?

Tags: php, performance, apache, https, time-wait

I force SSL because of the limitations in PHP sessions because I have AJAX logins (http and https don't keep the same session id on the same site).

Chrome network reports ~150ms in waiting for all resources.

I was able to reduce by 100ms to 150ms from 250ms by enabling keep-alive which was massive.

Are there any other tricks like that that can bring it down further?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this vague?  HTTPS seems to be pretty specific.  Waiting times too.  reduce.  how.  They seem pretty clear to me.  I gave a specific example (which should actually be added to the answers).  Another poster gave another example.  Please reopen.  Stack must be hungover today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) although is only supported by new browsers. There is a [mod_spdy](http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/) for apache released by google. That would help.

Nevertheless I found weird your statement *(http and https don't keep the same session id on the same site).* since I have used to have SSL only in the login pages. I never found that problem.

The limitation you are talking about is not of PHP. You cannot do ajax requests across different domains nor schemes (that is called [cross site posting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)). I would recommend you using some [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233691/how-to-cross-site-posting-and-redirection-in-asp-net-webforms) or to post to a stand only login page and tracking the referrer to send the user back to url they came from.

Comment: +1. Yes! SPDY is awesome!

Comment: Thank-you for the new knowledge!  I can enable CORS (and have been through the agony of finding out that Chrome will only allow process the first CORS response header).  My site's a single page site that ideally & in the past loaded HTTP.  It would send login information and other secure actions across HTTPS, and I couldn't get http to get $_SESSION variables from the logged in HTTPS.  Do you have a workaround?  Thanks again.

Comment: as I said, in my site you can switch across SSL to non-SSL without issue. Are you sure you don't have this [setting](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure) in _ON_ ? is the only reason I find for such behavior. Side note: don't try to play with CORS settings...It may fail in some cases and you will be nuts trying to find the issue.

Comment: Eh, my host doesn't support this.  Have any other miracles?  Thanks again!

Comment: For now (and probably in the future considering it's another goog), this gets the check.  Trying to find a way to use it now.  If I can get a 50% drop on waiting time, that'd bring me to 75ms, which would be pretty sweet since my wamp gets half that.

Comment: thanks! how do you know you host doesn't support this? save a file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on it and see if that value appears. if so you may set the value using [php_flag](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: @GabrielSosa cPanel.  Hoping for ISP Config 3 unless if there's another cp that supports.