# how to get enableCrossAppRedirects with form authentication asp.net working?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, single-sign-on

has anyone come across this property? I am actually trying to implement a single sign on for 2 asp.net websites in a different domain. Looking for a sample code for this?
many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a peek at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.enablecrossappredirects.aspx) if you are using cross domain you'll need to make sure you use cookie-less authentication too since the cookies won't be cross domain.

Theres a nice code sample from a author of another [Stack Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153851/enablecrossappredirects-where-is-the-cross-domain-feature-documented).

```
if (FormsAuthentication.EnableCrossAppRedirects)
{
text = context.Request.QueryString[name];
if (text != null && text.Length > 1)
{
    if (!cookielessTicket && FormsAuthentication.CookieMode == HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect)
    {
        cookielessTicket = CookielessHelperClass.UseCookieless(context, true, FormsAuthentication.CookieMode);
    }
    try
    {
        formsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(text);
    }
    catch
    {
        flag2 = true;
    }
    if (formsAuthenticationTicket == null)
    {
        flag2 = true;
    }
}
if (formsAuthenticationTicket == null || formsAuthenticationTicket.Expired)
{
    text = context.Request.Form[name];
    if (text != null && text.Length > 1)
    {
        if (!cookielessTicket && FormsAuthentication.CookieMode == HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect)
        {
            cookielessTicket = CookielessHelperClass.UseCookieless(context, true, FormsAuthentication.CookieMode);
        }
        try
        {
            formsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(text);
        }
        catch
        {
            flag2 = true;
        }
        if (formsAuthenticationTicket == null)
        {
            flag2 = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```